# Ways in R permutations package to go from cyclic to array notation

Tags: r, permutation, discrete-mathematics

The permutation in S4

```
1   2   3   4
|   |   |   |
3   1   4   2
```

can be expressed in cyclic notation with the command:

```
> as.word(c(3,1,4,2))
[1] (1342)
```

i.e.`(1342) = 1` goes to `3`; `3` goes to `4`; `4` goes to `2`; and `2` goes to `1`.

> The question is, How can I enter a permutation **in cycle notation** (say a simple transposition), and indicate that the permutation is in S4, so as to later be able to extract the array form?

I would like to be able to input, for instance, a transposition, e.g. `sigma =
 (3,4)`, and at the same time input that I'm dealing with the symmetric group 4 (S4), so that I can later print out that the permutation (`sigma`) in array form as `1  2  4  3`. In pseudocode:

```
w = as.cycle(c(3,4), permutation_length = 4)
```

And, slightly more complex, two transpositions in cyclic form defining a permutation `(1 2) (3 4)` entered at the same time. Again, in pseudocode:

```
w = as.cycle(list(c(1,2),c(3,4)))
```

---

If the permutation is entered in array form, e.g. `c(3,1,4,2)` I get the cyclic notation `(1342)` immediately:

```
> w = as.word(c(3,1,4,2))
> w
[1] (1342)
```

I can go back to the array notation using the output of `str()`, or slightly more elegantly with `as.vector()`.

```
> str(w)
 int [1, 1:4] 3 1 4 2
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "permutation" "word"
> as.vector(w)
[1] 3 1 4 2
```

Comment: Which package is this?

Comment: @Onyambu The package is `permutations`.

Comment: Since `as.word(c(3,1,4,2))` is just `c(3,1,4,2)` with a class attribute, I think the `as.vector` or `unclass` would be appropriate to get the original values. It only looks like `(1342)` because of `print.word` - if you do `print.default(as.word(c(3,1,4,2)))` you just get `c(3,1,4,2)` in a matrix back.

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you for your comments. This works fine, provided that the permutation in cycle form contains as many elements as the permutation in array form. I would like to know how to translate into array, a permutation of, say 4 digits, in which only the first two are transposed, i.e. `(1 2)`.

Comment: `as.word(c(2,1,3,4))` which prints like `(12)` still returns `c(2,1,3,4)` when doing `as.vector(as.word(c(2,1,3,4)))` - am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Do you mean you want `c(1,2)` returned instead?

Comment: @thelatemail I would like to be able to input in some form `(1, 2)`, together with the necessary information that we are dealing with the symmetric group 4, and get `(2, 1, 3, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

For one transposition:

```
w <- cycle2word(as.cycle(c(1,2)), 4)
as.vector(w)
# [1] 2 1 3 4
```

For the product of two transpositions:

```
w <- as.word(as.cycle(c(1,2)) * as.cycle(c(3,4)), 4)
as.vector(w)
# [1] 2 1 4 3
```